# How solve the problem with saving file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, file

I have problem with saving file in my database I have done the coding but somehow the coding did not read my first line code of File function because it keeps reading the else line which will save `noimage.jpg`if ,no file was detected during the submit. I think the problem is in my blade. But I can't figured it out.

[image]

The name of the file also did not appear after I done choosing the file.

The data also saved into my database but with noimage.jpg name even I have try to submit the image.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
      
       $this->validate($request,[
            'location' =>'required',
            'event_image'=>'image|nullable|max:1999',
            'availability'=>'required',
        ]);

        //handle the file upload
        if($request ->hasFile('event_image')){   // to check if user has opted to upload the file
        
            // get filename with extention
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('event_image')->getClientOriginalName();

            //get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //get ext (extention)
            $extension =$request->file('event_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //filename to store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename .'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //upload image
            $path = $request->file('event_image')->storeAs('public/event_images',$fileNameToStore);
       }else{
           $fileNameToStore ='noimage.jpg'; // if user dont have any file this name will be put on the database
       }

       $event = new Event;
       $event->location = $request->input('event_location');
       $event->event_image =$fileNameToStore;
       $event->availability =$request->input('event_availability');
       $event->admin_id = auth()->user()->id;

       $event->save();
}
```

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('event.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              @csrf
 <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="event_image" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Event Picture</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile" name="event_image" id="event_image"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: welcome to so, in your code at this line `if($request ->hasFile('event_image')){` , you have space between $request and object operator(arrow), is it a mistake while writing on stackoverflow or in the code which you execute as well

Comment: I would'nt store noimage.jpg in your DB. Better keep a NULL value in your DB and check in your view which image to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in `html input type file` element, it has `name attribute` missing:

This:

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
<label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile" name="event_image" id="event_image"></label>
```

Should be like this:

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="event_image" id="customFile">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile"  id="event_image"></label>
```

Comment: can't believe that I mispute the `name` tag thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `name` for getting form data

It should be

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="event_image ">
```